# Customizing the flask admin row actions

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-login, flask-admin

I want to add another button next to the edit and delete icons on flask admin list view. In addition, I want to send that row data to a route as a post request. I know that I have to edit the `admin/model/list.html` template, but I am not getting how to add this functionalities.

Can you provide any guidance?

[image: this is current default view for admin page]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to define custom action buttons for your view. This process is not described in the Flask-Admin tutorial but it is mentioned in the [API description](https://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/mod_model/#flask_admin.model.BaseModelView.column_extra_row_actions).

#### POST method

If you need to create a button for a POST method you should implement a jinja2 macro like this [delete_row](https://github.com/flask-admin/flask-admin/blob/master/flask_admin/templates/bootstrap3/admin/model/row_actions.html) action. It may look like this (I named the file "custom_row_actions.html"):

```
{% macro copy_row(action, row_id, row) %}
<form class="icon" method="POST" action="{{ get_url('.copy_view') }}">
  <input type="hidden" name="row_id" value="{{ get_pk_value(row) }}"/>
  <button type="submit" title="{{ _gettext('Copy record') }}">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-copy"></span>
  </button>
</form>
{% endmacro %}
```

Then you create a template for your list of records and import the macro library in it (I named it "my_list.html"):

```
{% extends 'admin/model/list.html' %}
{% import 'custom_row_actions.html' as custom_row_actions with context %}
```

After that you have to make a couple of changes in your view:

```
from flask_admin import expose
from flask_admin.contrib.sqla.view import ModelView
from flask_admin.model.template import TemplateLinkRowAction

class MyView(ModelView):
    list_template = "my_list.html"  # Override the default template
    column_extra_row_actions = [  # Add a new action button
        TemplateLinkRowAction("custom_row_actions.copy_row", "Copy Record"),
    ]

    @expose("/copy", methods=("POST",))
    def copy_view(self):
        """The method you need to call"""
```

#### GET method

Creating a button for a GET method is much simpler. You don't need to override templates, just add an action to your view:

```
from flask_admin import expose
from flask_admin.contrib.sqla.view import ModelView
from flask_admin.model.template import EndpointLinkRowAction

class MyView(ModelView):
    column_extra_row_actions = [  # Add a new action button
        EndpointLinkRowAction("glyphicon glyphicon-copy", ".copy_view"),
    ]

    @expose("/copy", methods=("GET",))
    def copy_view(self):
        """The method you need to call"""
```

#### Glyphicons

Glyphicons is the icon library which is bundled with the Bootstrap v3 library which is used by the Flask-Admin. You can use it if you chose this Bootstrap version on Flask-Admin initialization:

```
from flask_admin import Admin

admin = Admin(template_mode="bootstrap3")
```

You can look at the available icons in the [Bootsrap v3 documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#glyphicons).

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! I would only add that you can access the row `id` of the row that is clicked from inside of `copy_view` with `request.args['id']`.